# Python - Selenium web scraping but only repeats first item correct number of times

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

i have been trying to parse out a list from tradingview for quite a while and tried everything. This is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

WEBDRIVER_PATH = 'chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(WEBDRIVER_PATH)
URL = 'https://tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/market-movers-most-volatile/'
driver.get(URL)
print(driver.title)

# waiting data to be loaded
time.sleep(5)

stocks = []
for result in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="js-screener-container"]/div/table/tbody/tr'):
 stock = result.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="js-screener-container"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/span[2]').text
 stocks.append({'stock': stock})

print(stocks)
```

The problem is that it is only repeating the first item in the list correct number of first. I've seen plenty of cases that solves this by rewriting this part by adding a dot "."

```
stock = result.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="js-screener-container"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/span[2]').text
```

So it looks like this:

```
stock = result.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="js-screener-container"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/span[2]').text
```

But that gives me that breaks the code and give me this error instead:

```
    stock = result.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="js-screener-container"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/span[2]').text
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 351, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 659, in find_element
    {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id="js-screener-container"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/span[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can someone help me go further?

Kind regards

Comment: What text are you trying to get from each row?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for result in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="js-screener-container"]/div/table/tbody/tr'):
 stock = result.find_element_by_xpath('.//td/div/div/span[2]').text
 stocks.append({'stock': stock})

print(stocks)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept or upvote if you can.

Answer (score 0):

```html
browser = webdriver.Edge('msedgedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/market-movers-most-volatile/')
stocks = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#js-screener-container > div.tv-screener__content-pane > table > tbody').text
stocks = stocks.split('\n')
stocks2 = stocks[::4]
stocks_list = []
for stock in stocks2:
    stocks_list.append(stocks2)
```

this worked for me, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to move to elements to get all the names.

**code :**

```
driver.get('https://tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/market-movers-most-volatile/')
sleep(5)

stocks = []
for result in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".tv-screener__description"):
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(result).click().perform()
  print(result.text)
```

**o/p:**

```
PROSHARES TRUST II ULTRA VIX SHT TRM FUTR ETF ETF
LARIMAR THERAPEUTICS INC
LIZHI INC SPON ADS EACH REP 20 ORD SHS CL A DR
PROTAGENIC THERAPEUTICS INC
NABRIVA THERAPEUTICS PLC
PIERIS PHARMACEUTICALS INC
KINTARA THERAPEUTICS INC
ASENSUS SURGICAL INC
PLANET GREEN HOLDINGS CORP
TAKUNG ART CO LTD
BUILD A BEAR WORKSHOP INC
OWENS & MINOR INC
INNSUITES HOSPITALITY TRUST TF
EXPRESS INC
ASSERTIO HOLDINGS INC
INTRUSION INC
EZGO TECHNOLOGIES LTD
CARLOTZ INC
UCLOUDLINK GROUP INC SPON ADS EACH REP 10 ORD SHS CL A DR
IT TECH PACKAGING INC
OHIO VALLEY BANCORP
ORIENTAL CULTURE HLDG LTD
VALLON PHARMACEUTICALS INC
LIPOCINE INC
PDS BIOTECHNOLOGY CORPORATION
PDL COMMUNITY BANCORP
ONDAS HOLDINGS INC
GSX TECHEDU INC SPON ADS EACH REP 0.666 ORD SHS CL A DR
AKERNA CORP
INTERCEPT PHARMACEUTICALS INC
TRAVERE THERAPEUTICS INC
MOXIAN INC
SEACOR MARINE HOLDINGS INC
GREENBOX POS
21VIANET GROUP INCORPORATED SPON ADS EACH REPR 6 ORD SHS A DR
ARCIMOTO INC
BAOSHENG MEDIA GROUP HLDGS LTD
LA JOLLA PHARMACEUTICAL CO
READING INTERNATIONAL INC
RENESOLA LTD SPON ADS EACH REP 10 ORD DR
AMC ENTERTAINMENT HOLDINGS INC
APTEVO THERAPEUTICS INC
SCOPUS BIOPHARMA INC
NOVAN INC
INSPIRED ENTERTAINMENT INC
DYADIC INTERNATIONAL INC
HUDSON TECHNOLOGIES INC
LIQUID MEDIA GROUP LTD
EHANG HOLDINGS LIMITED SPON ADS EACH REP 2 ORD SHS CL A DR
PAINREFORM LTD
YIELD10 BIOSCIENCE INC
BEAM GLOBAL
PROVENTION BIO INC
SELECTA BIOSCIENCES INC
LI AUTO INC SPN ADS ECH REP 2 ORD SHS CL A DR
REX AMERICAN RESOURCES CORPORATION
WALDENCAST ACQUISITION CORP
KUKE MUSIC HOLDING LIMITED SPON ADS REPRESENTING ONE CL A ORD SHS DR
SKYLINE CHAMPION CORPORATION
TDH HOLDINGS INC
FUBOTV INC
GAMESTOP CORPORATION
UP FINTECH HOLDING LIMITED SPON ADS EACH REP 15 ORD SHS CL A DR
RA MEDICAL SYSTEMS INC
DICKS SPORTING GOODS INC
MICROVISION INC WASHINGTON
VISTAGEN THERAPEUTICS INC
TELLURIAN INC
JAGUAR HEALTH INC
SCORE MEDIA AND GAMING INC
BOQII HOLDING LIMITED SPON ADS EACH REP 0.75 CL A ORD SHS DR
APPLIED THERAPEUTICS INC
ELECTRAMECCANICA VEHS CORP
RANPAK HOLDINGS CORP
BURNING ROCK BIOTECH LTD SPON ADS EACH REP 1 ORD SHS CL A DR
ASIA PACIFIC WIRE & CABLE
BELLICUM PHARMACEUTICALS
DOUBLEVERIFY HLDGS INC
EBANG INTERNATIONAL HLDGS INC
CANAAN INC SPON ADS EACH REP 15 ORD SHS CL A DR
URBAN OUTFITTERS INC
AGEAGLE AERIAL SYSTEMS INC
ABCELLERA BIOLOGICS INC
DOLPHIN ENTERTAINMENT INC
ZK INTERNATIONAL GROUP CO LTD
CELLECT BIOTECHNOLOGY LTD SPON ADS EACH REP 100 ORD SHS(POST SPLT) DR
REGIONAL HEALTH PROPERTIES INC REIT
ANNOVIS BIO INC
TUYA INC SPON ADS EACH REP 1 CL A ORD SHS DR
RLX TECHNOLOGY INC SPON ADS EACH REP 1 CL A ORD SHS DR
CINEDIGM CORPORATION
BIT DIGITAL INC
NAM TAI PPTY INC
EXAGEN INC
WRAP TECHNOLOGIES INC
IMAGE SENSING SYSTEMS INC
WUNONG NET TECHNOLOGY CO LTD
WORKHORSE GROUP INC
BIG 5 SPORTING GOODS CORP
KOSS CORP
```